# How to use keyboard keys in other classess than mainwindow in Qt?

Tags: qt

i'm making an 2048 game implementation and want to use w,a,s,d keyboard keys to move number matrix up, down, left and right, but i can't figure out how to call keyboard event function in my main.cpp. Here's the code:

main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication game_2048(argc, argv);

    Matrix game = Matrix(4);

    srand (time(NULL));

    QWidget *window_main = new QWidget;
    window_main->setWindowTitle("2048 Game");
    QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout;
    window_main->setFixedSize(600,400);
    QPushButton ***polja = new QPushButton**[4];
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        polja[i] = new QPushButton*[4];
        for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
        {
            QString name = QString::number(game._matrix[i][j]);
            polja[i][j] = new QPushButton(window_main);
            polja[i][j]->setFixedHeight(100);
            polja[i][j]->setText(name);
            polja[i][j]->move(100 +100*i,100*j);
        }
    }

    window_main->setLayout(layout);

    window_main->show();

    return game_2048.exec();
```

and mainwindow.cpp:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e)
{
    if(e->key() == Qt::Key_W)
        game->playUp();
    if(e->key() == Qt::Key_S)
        game->playDown();
    if(e->key() == Qt::Key_D)
        game->playRight();
    if(e->key() == Qt::Key_A)
        game->playLeft();

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: that happens automatically

Comment: You're implementing a MainWindow, but you're using a standard QWidget in main.cpp. Your MainWindow::keyPressEvent implementation looks correct, but you might want to call the default keyPressEvent afterwards (maybe only in the case another key was pressed).

Comment: Thank you for your response, but can you be a little more clear? I didn't understand how I can do that. I'm pretty new to Qt, so a sample code would be much appreciated.

Comment: Inside your 'main.cpp', have an '#include "MainWindow.h" at the top. And replace your 'QWidget * window_main = new QWidget;' by 'MainWindow * window_main = new MainWindow;'

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the `MainWindow` class that you created. Try the following changes in `main.cpp`:

```
#include "MainWindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ...
    // QWidget *window_main = new QWidget;
    MainWindow *window_main = new MainWindow;
    ...
}
```

The `keyPressEvent` looks okay, but maybe you'll want to pass on other key presses to the original `QMainWindow` `keyPressEvent` implementation:

```
void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e)
{
    if(e->key() == Qt::Key_W)
        game->playUp();
    else if(e->key() == Qt::Key_S)
        game->playDown();
    else if(e->key() == Qt::Key_D)
        game->playRight();
    else if(e->key() == Qt::Key_A)
        game->playLeft();
    else
        QMainWindow::keyPressEvent( e );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. With your help I figured it out.Cheers!